# jmx is not enabled to receive remote connections

Tags: cassandra, jvm

I am not sure why 7199 is listening on 127.0.0.1,how can i make 7199 listen to hostip address.

my cassandra-env.sh config as below for JVM

JMX_PORT="7199"

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.68.0.45"
LOCAL_JMX=no

if [ "$LOCAL_JMX" = "yes" ]; then

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=$JMX_PORT -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"

else
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"

Comment: There should be a variable with name *LOCAL_JMX* set to "yes"; set it to "no", restart the service and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I have been fighting this issue too.  Is been not as easy as shown on the tutorials.

I solved the issue like this:

1. Add environment variable LOCAL_JMX to my .bashrc file:

```
    #Set LOCAL_JMX
    export LOCAL_JMX=no
```

2. At cassandra-env.sh disable password authentication (test environmnent!!):

```
    JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
    #  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"
```

3. Restart each node(s)

Comment: I believe the confusion stems from this bizarre BASH gibberish "x$LOCAL_JMX" = "x" which as I recall says something like "the variable has not been initialized". Pretty sure that is it so you can code LOCAL_JMX=no right in cassandra-env.sh as I did and it corrects the issue without side effects or change .bashrc as shown above but watch for side effects.